# Issue with Spring retry for Exception Block

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

I am trying to use retry https://www.mscharhag.com/spring/spring-retry but facing an issue. I have a method

```
public String methodA( T Object)  {
    try{

    }catch(someException sme){
       return fixit(Object);
    }
}

@Retryable(value = {someException.class}, maxAttempts = 3)
public String fixit( T Object)  {
    return x;
}
```

Where I need to try fixit 3 times if the same exception is thrown. But somehow retryable is not working for a method I am calling from exception block.

Any pointers of whats missing? If I add the annotation on top of methodA it works, but thats not the behaviour I want. I tried @Recover,but it is called only after the maxAttempts is tried and not each time exception is hit.

Comment: Spring AOP works using proxies, which means only method calls into the object will be proxied. You are calling a method from inside the proxy.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `@Retryable` is working with AOP interceptors and Java proxies.

The issue you are facing is that you are calling a method within the same class and therefore the AOP proxy does not get involved. This is why your code starts to work as expected when you move the annotation to the method `methodA` (since I assume that method gets call from another class).

What you can do is move your method `fixit` to another Spring bean and inject it into the Spring bean with `methodA`

```
@Component
class ClassWithMethodA {

  @Autowired
  private AnotherBean bean;

  public String methodA( T o)  {
    try{

    }catch(someException sme){
       return bean.fixit(o);
    }
  }
}

@Component
class AnotherBean {
  @Retryable(value = {someException.class}, maxAttempts = 3)
  public String fixit( T o)  {
    return x;
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this . But same issue. It call the fixit of AnotherBean but just once

Comment: Have you added `@EnableRetry` to a `@Configuration` class?